# How to join two vse video edit projects?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, append

I have a second part for my video editing project in the VSE that I have edited separately. I would like to append it to the main part, so that I could combine the strips, cuts and so on. How can I do it?

The append feature in the main menu seems to be designed for other purposes. But for someone like me that only uses Blender as a video editor, that seems not to be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have *File1* and *File2*, and want to transfer the clips from *File1* to *File2*.

1. Open File2 and select File > Append <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Navigate to File1 and "open" it. In Append mode we can view the contents of the file. Click on the scene folder of the file and select the scene, which you want to append. You can see the name of the scene in File1, if you open it and look in the top Header/Info Bar.
3. After selecting and appending the extra scene you can switch to it in the current File2. Since both scenes in File1 and File2 had the same name, the appended scene from File1 was renamed to Scene.001.
   [image: scene]
4. Open the scene originally from File1 (but now in File2), select all strips and copy them with Ctrl C.
5. Open the other scene and paste the strips.

Comment: How can I accept your answer twice? Omg, omg, omg, this trick has suddenly unleashed such power!!! From now on I can work on several pieces separately without having a giant timeline. Thank you!!!!

Comment: You could just add a new scene in the same file in future. You don't have to create a new file for another sequencer track, since each scene has its own sequencer tracks.

Comment: Can you not even add a further "master" scene (just banned like it) in which you just use scene strips to mix it all together once you're done with all the individual scenes? ;-)

Comment: @Samoth Yes, although this is slightly trickier, since the length of the clips isn't updated and transistions will be more difficult. However, you could add this information to a new answer or as an edited note to this answer.